# nginx is wrongly serving all subdomains

Tags: nginx

My nginx server is serving content to all subdomains, even though I've removed the default_server from the main server block.

So there is absolutely no reference whatsoever to "default_server" or (for example) to subdomain.domain.com in any of the nginx config files and yet, if I go to that URL, it gives me the first site which is listening on port 80 (which specifies a different subdomain in the nginx config).

It's confusing the hell out of me - I want it to stop giving me anything on that domain so that I can then point that new subdomain to a new location.

Any ideas?!

Comment: Off-topic as it's not a programming question. Ask on [sf]

Comment: Fair enough - didn't realise there was another forum.

It's here, if anyone's interested -> http://serverfault.com/questions/661309/nginx-is-wrongly-serving-all-subdomains